# What is lazy evaluation in lodash.js?

Tags: javascript, lodash

How does Lazy Evaluation work in lodash.js?

```
var chosen = _(gems).filter(priceLt(10)).take(3).value();
```

How does this work?

Comment: http://filimanjaro.com/blog/2014/introducing-lazy-evaluation/

Comment: thanks, but i want to know  the the concrete process of realization.

I've read your article before asking questions.

Comment: How does *what* work? Have you taken a look at the library code? What parts in the explanation of lazy evaluation did you not understand?

Comment: @zabusa are you sure it is how lodash handle lazy eval? That it translate to`result[i] = func3(func2(func1(source[i])));`? Try `_([1,2,3]).map(x => x+1).filter(x => x > 0).value()` and observe those two function are called linearly.

Comment: From my observation Lodash delay function execution until you call `.value()`. Which is different than the thunk and lazy eval concept in FP world.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy eval in lodash is simply memorize functions and delay evaluation until you call `value()`. Taken an example of `_([1,2,3]).map(x => x+1).filter(x => x > 0).value()`

```
// wrap value in a lazy wrapper.
_([1,2,3]) => {
  value: [1,2,3]
  actions: []
}

// register functions
.map() => {
  value: [1,2,3]
  actions: [map]
}

.filter() => {
  value: [1,2,3]
  actions: [map, filter]
}

// unwrap and evaluate
.value() => [1,2,3].map(x => x+1).filter(x => x > 0) => [2,3,4]
```

Note non of the functions are executed but simply memorized function description before last step.